# MySql how to handle multilingual Product Listing data for best performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, internationalization

I have one question about placing data in MySql database. I want to create product listing type of web app, where should be few fields like: name (multilingual field that will contain up to 256 characters for each language), weight, width, height, color, material (and some other fields that should contain only numbers and will not have to need changes for each language). So I am stacked and I don't know how to handle this task correctly.

- I can use single table for all my data and create new columns for new
  language, but the problem will arise when developer will try to
  change the width, or height information on database. So he/she will
  have to change this single parameter for all languages.
- I can use 2 tables, 1 for multilingual "names" and another for
  "Products",    where 1 field from first table will indicate the
  ID of second table. In this case if developer will need to change some parameter, he/she will change only 1 field in the "products" table.

I know this question can appear as subjective, but think some other folks, who are trying to create multilingual web app, like mine, will find the answer useful.

P.S.
sorry for my English skills

Comment: It's my mistake -- sorry. I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID tagging parts that has multiple translations using a single column sounds reasonable. Then you can have a centralized server to store application specific translation files that is always sync with ids to handle different types of clients. Any client should be able to fetch specific translation data using a custom call. Such mechanism can easily make use of caching optimizations and will always guarantee an up to date translation.

Answer (score 1):

Internationalization of database columns like this can get tricky, and there is indeed no "one true way".

In your example, breaking out the names into a separate table seems like a straight-forward case of good normalisation - I certainly would never consider duplicating the entire row just to translate one column. However, that approach gets unwieldy the more columns you end up translating - in an extreme case, for every column in the original table, you now have a new table, and your original table exists only to hold them all together. (Relational database theorists love schemas like this - look up 5NF and 6NF - but people actually trying to *use* the database may not be so keen on having to work with that many `JOIN`s).

Another approach is to have one large table of text strings, each stored with a unique ID + language, and then where you would normally have a `VarChar` column, you instead store the relevant ID in the translation table. Alternatively, you can make the translation table store the context (e.g. table, column name, and primary key) of each string directly. This results in a less "cluttered" feel to the database, but the table of text strings is rather odd in terms of data modelling: they have no connection to each other expect for being strings.

I have played with an alternative solution, which [I called "Atomic Translations" in this blog post a few years back](http://rwec.co.uk/blog/2009/11/atomic-translations-part-1/) (that post includes more details on the approaches I've just mentioned as well, by the way). My idea was that instead of treating it as a normalisation problem, you can treat it as a data type problem: the product's name is a single piece of information, and the translations are just aspects of a single value. In practical terms, rather than breaking out the data into multiple tables, you squeeze it all into the original column. [My specific implementation is for PostgreSQL](http://rwec.co.uk/blog/2009/12/atomic-translations-part-2/), so I don't know how practical this would be in MySQL, and there are some tricky issues around performance if the type is not well-integrated with the DBMS, but I've not found a flaw in the fundamental approach as yet.